# How to override default log4j properties in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Currently we are using `hadoop.root.logger="INFO,console"` for mapreduce and spark jobs. I want override with `"WARN,console"` , I tried to set global variable

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,console"
```

in `hadoop-env.sh` but its not working . i can see info,warn,error in yarn log. how can i override these settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `yarn-env.sh` has these lines which override the log levels for YARN processes.

```
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Dhadoop.root.logger=${YARN_ROOT_LOGGER:-INFO,console}"
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Dyarn.root.logger=${YARN_ROOT_LOGGER:-INFO,console}"
```

If `YARN_ROOT_LOGGER` is not set, yarn log level is set to `INFO`.

Add the variable `YARN_ROOT_LOGGER` in `hadoop-env.sh`,

```
export YARN_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,console"
```